# Amazon SQS Message and "Could not find a transformer to transform SimpleDataType..."

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I'm using very simple flow, where I have tried to set message attribute( for SQS) in flowVars, so that it will be reflected in my SQS Queue. I have used this link https://github.com/mulesoft/sqs-connector/blob/master/src/test/resources/automation-test-flows.xml for references(In the link they referred by using flow vars). But i'm getting the error like

```
  "Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String,mimeType='*/*'}"   to "SimpleDataType{type=java.util.Map,        mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)"
```

Pleasse find my config xml

```
  <flow name="sqsFlow1" doc:name="sqsFlow1">
  <sqs:receive-messages  config-ref="Amazon_SQS"  doc:name="Amazon SQS (Streaming)" numberOfMessages="5"  visibilityTimeout="11"/>
   <set-variable variableName="setMessageAtt" value="[name:&quot;John&quot;]" doc:name="Variable"/>
   sqs:send-message config-ref="Amazon_SQS1"    doc:name="Amazon SQS" >
        <sqs:message-attributes ref="#[flowVars.setMessageAtt]"/>
    </sqs:send-message>
   </flow>
```

I understand the  value which I try to return as `String`, but it is expecting `Map`. Is there any way we can change the string vaue in to  Map inside flow variable itself ( Via MEL). If not, how we can handle the scenario. I have tried multiple scenario , but it is not working.

Your help is required.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mule you can represent a Map as: `#[key1 : value1, key2 : value2, . . .]`

For example, with mel:

```
#[['title':'value','description':'value','status':'404','bit': false]]
```

is equivalent to

```
Map<String, Object>
```

I hope to help;